# how to enable firebase offline data and pass the data to recyclerview adapter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I work on android chat app and it work fine until i added this line to myapplication class`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` to enable getting offline  users messages  it cause my app to crash with this error message

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
```

and if i removed this line from myApplication class app work fine , i know it is because i get data in pojo class ,how to do that  to get benefit of firebase offline capabilities and pass these data to recyclerview adapter
my fetch message method

```
DatabasReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getreference().child("messages")
    private void fetchMessages() {
            if (mChildEventListener == null) {
                mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            Messages messages = snapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                            messagesList.add(messages);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);
    
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
    
    
                    }
ref.addChildEventLustener(mChildEventListener)
```

My database structure

```
"Users": {
    "useId": {
      "name": m,
      "image": true
    }
"useId": {
      "name": n,
      "image": true
    }
}
"Messages" :{
   "mesageId" : {
      messsage:"hello"
      from: "MERjk5566699jjg"
      photoUrl : null
     date:145885665255
     seen :false
```

and message class

```
public class Messages {
    private String message,from ,photoUrl;
    private long date;
    private boolean seen;

    public Messages() {
    }

    public Messages(String message, String from, String photoUrl, long date, boolean seen) {
        this.message = message;
        this.from = from;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
        this.date = date;
        this.seen = seen;
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot. Besides that, please also add the reference on which you are attaching the listener.

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Messages` class.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any property in the database called "date" which holds a String instead of a long value?

Comment: No I don't , this error only happen when i added FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); and if i comment it the app work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question to help anyone if he get an error like

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to long
```

when using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);`
the error occurred because I retrieve  data like

```
Messages messages = snapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
```

it is not right to do that when using firebase offline ,the right way to retrieve every child like

```
String text = snapshot.child("message").getValue().toString;
```

and then create instance of your class and pass it to adapter